# How to convert numeric values with quotes in CSV to int type

Tags: python, pandas

Data is below

```
no,store_id,revenue,profit,state,country
'0','101','779183','281257','WD','India'
'1','101','144829','838451','WD','India'
'2','101','766465','757565','AL','Japan'
'3','102','766465','757565','AL','Japan'
```

Code is below

```
import pandas as pd  
data = pd.read_csv("1.csv") 
dummies = pd.get_dummies(data)
dummies.head(10)
```

data.info() is `Object` for all the column.

How to convert to automatically to `new object column` to dummies, For example here `TEAM` is `object` need to convert to get_dummies. If some one add tomorrow `names` column it is also need to convert to dummies

- data.info() is `object` for all the column
- How to convert automatically assign `int` to numeric column and `object` to non-numeric column
- Tomorrow some one might add new column may be numeric or non-numeric
- How to apply get_dummies after that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While reading CSV file using [**`pd.read_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) set `quotechar` parameter to `'`(default is `"`)

From [docs `pd.read_csv` under `quotechar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

**quotecharstr** (length 1), optional:

> The character used to denote the start and end of a quoted item. Quoted items can include the delimiter and it will be ignored.

```
from io import StringIO
text = """no,store_id,revenue,profit,state,country
'0','101','779183','281257','WD','India'
'1','101','144829','838451','WD','India'
'2','101','766465','757565','AL','Japan'
'3','102','766465','757565','AL','Japan'"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text),quotechar='\'') # or quotechar = "'"
print(df.dtypes)
no           int64
store_id     int64
revenue      int64
profit       int64
state       object
country     object
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ch3steR's solution is perfect.

Just to extend it, you can use converters in conjunction to efficiently handle conversions in case you would want to.

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), converters={'no': D.Decimal, 'store_id': D.Decimal})
```